# How can I stream a Twilio video room to thousands?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, twilio, webrtc

I'm trying to build a solution using Twilio Programmable Video, where the video call between the participants can be streamed to (potentially) thousands. I understand that depending on the room type, Twilio can only take up to 50 participants. Is there a way I can somehow "feed" the video/audio track from all the participants to a streaming service like Wowza, TokBox, etc. and achieve this?

p.s. I have already scouted all the relevant questions here, haven't found a definitive answer yet.

Thanks,
Iraklis

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that this can be done using Twilio but requires a non-trivial integration.

The steps are the following:

(1) The developer creates a Twilio Room.

(2) The developer connects to the room a fake participant running on a browser driver (e.g. selenium or equivalent).

(3) The fake participant screen is captured. This can be done using ffmpeg. Such capture is published to a live streaming server such as Wowza.

(4) Wowza publishes the stream using RTMP or MPEG/DASH to a CDN like Amazon CloudFront or equivalent.

Twilio does not provide development integration in steps 2, 3 and 4. That needs to be handled by the developer.

Comment: I see, interesting, thanks for your answer Alan. Do you know of anyone/any company that has implemented this setup? Where did you hear this from if you don't mind me asking? It would be amazing to dig deeper into this and understand the complexities of this integration.

Comment: Zoom has direct to Facebook Live and You Tube Live steaming, https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360028478292-Streaming-a-Meeting-or-Webinar-on-YouTube-Live and https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115000350406-Streaming-a-Meeting-or-Webinar-on-Facebook-Live.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I'm looking to live stream on my platform though.

Comment: a little late but here is an article from Apollo  that used a similar architecture. https://www.apollo350.com/post/how-to-live-stream-from-a-twilio-video-conference